# Introduce branching to existing project best practice for TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

We have TFS 2013, currently for the team project working we don't have any branches, basically just a plain folder structure with various solutions in them.

With the goal to introduce release management, the intention is to create several branche, e.g. development/main/releases

As I was told I cannot 'disturb' the project team developers from their day to day work since there are other projects being worked on, question, what is the best practice to do this? Create a separate team project? How can we adopt the branching practice without asking all the developers.

Please help point a direction for this or share some thought on this, any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately to do this you'll have to "disturb" the development team. You have 2 options. 1. Come up with a process in isolation and then disturb them when it goes live. 2. Collaborate with them on a process and work together to meet your requirements. (Being able to release your code to production is a key requirement for any project, sadly it's so obvious that it never gets added to the backlog / project plan and is always treated as a afterthought)

I recommend option 2. Without collaboration you're just going to end up causing resentment that you're imposing something on the Devs and they'll fight it tooth and nail. Also without the development team being involved you'll miss something important that will make the process brittle and difficult to maintain.

You'll need to get buy in from the Developers to implement a branching strategy as it will have a significant impact on them, they need to understand why you're doing this and what the benefits are, both to them and the business. They don't necessarily have to do any of the work, but they need to know what you're doing and why, they will also need to know when the changes are coming so that they can plan for the change.

Firstly you need to real the [ALM Rangers version control guidance](https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).

Secondly you need to get the developers to read it as well. They will be responsible for maintaining the code and merging it between branches. They will need to know when and where they need to check in various changes (such as hotfixes), and what process they should follow when code is ready for release.

Finally, regarding your question about where the branches should be located. It would be better to locate the all branches in the same Team Project rather than having your Dev branch in a separate Team Project.